# Need to update one field in firebase kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update only one field with sum of existing and new enter amount. How to do that?

I haven't idea to continue this.

```
val value1 = amountText.getText().toString().toDouble()
                            val value2 = rootRef.child("BankDetails").child(sessionId).child("accountBalance")
                            var valueT = value1 + value2
```

I need to update only account balance in bank details. I'm still learning kotlin.

**Edited**

```
data class BankDetails (val accountBalance:Double,  val bankAccNo:String,val emailAddress:String ){
   
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${this.emailAddress}, ${this.bankAccNo}"
    }
    
    fun toDouble() {
         this.accountBalance
    }
    
}
```

[image: BankDetails]

```
{
  "BankDetails" : {
    "aaa@gmail,com" : {
      "accountBalance" : 200,
      "bankAccNo" : 12345678,
      "emailAddress" : "aaa@gmail,com"
    },
    "abi@gmail,com" : {
      "accountBalance" : 3000,
      "bankAccNo" : "123xxxxx",
      "emailAddress" : "abi@gmail,com"
    }
  },
  "User" : {
    "abi@gmail,com" : {
      "age" : 23,
      "bankAccNo" : "123xxxxxxx",
      "emailAddress" : "abi@gmail,com",
      "fullName" : "Abi",
      "passwordRegister" : "123456",
      "phoneNo" : 713615554
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and indicate the exact field you want to update.

Comment: I still cannot see your database schema.

Comment: @AlexMamo Database schema means firebase or? I updated again. Plzz tell me If I'm wrong because I'm still student.

Comment: So you want to update the value of `accountBalance` with what?

Comment: @AlexMamo with new entered value. ( in edit text field)

Comment: @AlexMamo Added database schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increment the value of `accountBalance` with the value of `amountText`, do it as simple as:

```
val value1 = amountText.getText().toString().toDouble()
val accountBalanceRef = rootRef.child("BankDetails").child(sessionId).child("accountBalance")
accountBalanceRef.setValue(ServerValue.increment(value1))
```

If you want, you can also attach a complete listener to the setValue() operation to see if something goes wrong.